# Недоступно изменение GridView

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, sql-server, .net

Подключаю GridView к таблице базы данных через конструктор выбора источника данных. Хочу выбрать удалять, вставлять и обновлять данные. Нажимаю Advanced, но там все элементы оказываются недоступными. **Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чём может быть проблема?** (См. рисунок.)

[image]

Comment: Ключ есть?

Comment: Попробуй использовать TemplateFiled, вместо BoundFiled